# How to add relationship to table rows based on column value in psql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a table of `patients` and a table of `doctors`.
I would like to assign a `doctor` to every `patient`.
Doctors may have many patients but a Patient will belong to a single Doctor.
I would like to assign a specific doctor based on the `born_on` value of the `patient`.

Currently I am using a `SET` and `WHERE` clause to assign patients with a `born_on` below `10` to the doctor with an `id` of `1`.

```
 UPDATE patients p
  SET doctor_id = d.id
  FROM doctors d
  WHERE DATE_PART('year', AGE(p.born_on)) < 10
  AND d.id = 1;
```

How could I, in minimal number of queries, assign all patients to a doctor based on their `born_on` attribute.

The conditions are below

```
age - d.id
< 10 is 1
< 20 is 2
< 30 is 3
< 40 is 4
< 50 is 5
< 60 is 6
< 70 is 7
< 80 is 8
< 90 is 9
>= 100 is 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wondering, if you already know the condition for update, do you have to go to the Doctor's table (meaning something like below)

```
UPDATE patients p
  SET doctor_id = case DATE_PART('year', AGE(p.born_on)) 
                  when < 10 then 1
                  when < 20 then 2 
                  ...
                  end
```

Comment: This syntax has to be `CASE expression WHEN value...` so `< 10` won't work.  But you can do `CASE WHEN expression < 10 THEN 1` etc.